# What's the process to calculate symmetric group multiplication

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

I know how $fg$ works, and I know how to get the target matrix, but I don't understand how to get $(124)(35)$ before the matrix.

Please enlighten me the detailed process.

\begin{equation}
f=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 3
\end{array}\right)(45)=\left(\begin{array}{lllll}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & 5 & 4
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
g=\left(\begin{array}{lll}
1 & 2 & 5
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ll}
3 & 4
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{lllll}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
2 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 1
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
f g=f \circ g=\left(\begin{array}{lll}
1 & 2 & 4
\end{array}\right)(35)=\left(\begin{array}{lllll}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
2 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 3
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

Similar confusion:

\begin{equation}
(143)(23)(24)=(14)(23)
\end{equation}

Comment: I know it's trivial to all group theorists, I am new to this, sorry

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to simply compute the cycles? For each values 1 through 5, simply see what $fg$ sends them to.
$$ 1 \stackrel{g}{\to} 2 \stackrel{f}\to 2 \stackrel g \to 5 \stackrel f \to 4 \stackrel{g}\to 3 \stackrel f \to 1 $$
so your first cycle will be $(1 \, 2 \, 4)$. Your second cycle is
$$ 3 \stackrel g\to 4 \stackrel f \to 5 \stackrel g \to 1 \stackrel f \to 3 $$
so your second cycle is $(3 \, 5)$. Thus $fg = (1\,2\,4)(3\,5)$.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is that saying: (1 3)(4 5)(1 2 5)(3 4) => (1 2 4)(3 5)? cuz what I don't get it does the multiplication still make any sense isolating from the matrix?

Comment: I mean I totally understand what you replied. But the analysis still rely on the matrix, I mean if you can check out my 'Similar confusion' in my question, I still don't know how the multiplication works individually.

Comment: If you want to do the multiplication individually, you can just apply the cycles from right to left. For example, $1 \to 2$, $2 \to 5 \to 4$, $4 \to 3 \to 1$ gives $(1\,2 \,4)$. $3 \to 4 \to 5$ and $5 \to 1 \to 3$ gives $(3\, 5)$. Does that help?

Comment: so can I say, the multiplication only makes sense when we consider its matrix meaning, right? I couldn't get a straight answer without building the matrix, right?